# Make Excel marks the repeated rows with a lot of data in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have this Excel archive with 5 columns of data, and then, about 4,000 rows of different data for each column, but I can’t find a way to make that Excel marks the repeated rows?

[image: Excel]
I have tried using the [Conditional Formating Rules](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), but it only marks the repeated cells, not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try applying the concatenate function before using conditional formatting.
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/04/11/highlight-duplicate-records-in-an-excel-list/

Comment: Thank you so much, that Concatenate formula is awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Go back to Conditional Formatting and delete any prior rules you have created for this purpose, then (full columns A:H selected) create a new rule using the option to *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. Supply the following to the *Format values where this formula is true* textbox:

`=COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,$D:$D,$D1,$E:$E,$E1,$F:$F,$F1,$G:$G,$G1)>1`

You likened your requirement to the existing *Format only unique or duplicate items* options so I assumed that you wanted both the first and any subsequent duplicates highlighted.

*Caveat:* If you have more than ~1000 rows then you may experience some latent calculation lag. This could be reduced with a *helper* column holding a concatenated value as mentioned in the previous reply. Which method you choose will depend upon the number of row within the conditional formatting rule's *Applies to:* region and what you feel you can live with.